# prove that the group$ R^n $ is isomorphic to the group $(Diag(n, R),+)$

Tags: matrices, group-isomorphism

Show that, the group $R^n $is isomorphic to the group$ (Diag(n, R),+)$ consisting of $n\times n$ diagonal matrices having positive real diagonal entries.

Recall: the group operation on $R^n$ is the componentwise addition, and the group operation on $(Diag(n, R),+)$ is the matrix multiplication

Comment: what you tried for this question ... this site is not for home work ...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Where are you getting stuck exactly? Can you find the identity element? Can you describe the map? Can you prove it is an isomorphism?